# quietDown a job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jobs

I came across /quietDown URL [jenkinsQuietDown](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216118748-How-to-Start-Stop-or-Restart-your-Instance-) to pause a Jenkins Instance. I want to know if it can be used to only pause a job without impacting other running jobs on the instance.

I want to pause a particular job on failure, and restart from the top of the queue after resolution. This is to maintain order of execution of the job for different parameters.

Comment: When in quietDown mode, any running freestyle jobs will continue to completion. Any pipeline jobs will complete the running stage, then pause. They next stage will resume when unquieced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [jenkinsQuietDown](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216118748-How-to-Start-Stop-or-Restart-your-Instance-) command work on jenkins level, not on job level.

`quietDown: Put Jenkins in a Quiet mode, in preparation for a restart. In that mode Jenkins don’t start any build`